# Is it possible to create a WCF service endpoint to process dead letters from Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, servicebus

Looking through the Azure Service Bus documentation and posts on the web I can only find examples of dead-letter processing that use the MessageReceiver classes to read dead-letters from the $DeadLetterQueue.

While the above scenario works fine, I'm curious if the following scenario is supported:

Can I point a separate WCF service endpoint to essentially listen for messages on the direct dead-letter queue (e.g. sb://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/MyTopic/subscriptions/MySubscription/$DeadLetterQueue)?

The expectation is that as new dead-letters are added, this listening WCF service endpoint is triggered to handle the message. The experiments that I've performed so far indicate that this is not supported.

Anyone know if Azure Service Bus can handle this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, Currently i cannot find any documentation about this. You can submit a feature request on http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/40626-windows-azure-appfabric-feature-voting. 
As a workaround, you can use MessageReceiver to read the messages, and then if you like, you can send the message to a WCF service.

Comment: I've opted to setup a scheduled task that will polls the $DeadLetterQueue at a regular interval and forwards any dead-letters  to a handler that I specify.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work and will try it out, just wanted to know if you had seen the following [guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.netmessagingbinding.aspx): When using the WCF publish/subscribe service model, when adding the service endpoint you must specify the topic URI as the address, and the subscription URI as the listening URI. You should be able to substitue the listening URI with sb://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/MyTopic/subscriptions/MySubscription/$DeadLetterQueue

Comment: In my tests I pointed the 'listenUri' at the subscription as you mention and also made sure that the 'address' is pointed at the topic. Unfortunately, the dead letters do not trigger the listening endpoint.

Comment: Can you try to first recieve from the regular Queue endpoint too? I believe there is a service issue where deadletter messages are sometimes not enqueued till there is a regular reciever on the main Queue.

Comment: The service that is listening for messages is hosted out of IIS with AppFabric auto-start enabled. The regular queue receivers started before the dead letter queue receiver. In addition, this may not guarantee that the regular receiver is listening before the deadletter receiver and would still be a problem.